# Child Component not updating after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react, and I am making a simple ToDoApp. I set some todo data from a JSON file in the state of my App Component and use the values to populate a Child component. I wrote a method to be called each time the onChange event is fired on a checkbox element and flip the checkbox by updating the state. Thing is this code worked perfectly fine before, but it's not anymore. The state gets updated accordingly when I change the checkbox, but it doesn't update in the child element, I'd like to know why. Here's my code

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import toDoData from "./toDosData";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            toDoData: toDoData
        };
        this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnChange(key)
    {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let newState = prevState.toDoData.map(currentData => {
                if(currentData.id === key)
                    currentData.completed = !currentData.completed;
                return currentData;
            });
            return {toDoData: newState};
        });
    }

    render() {
        let toDoComponents = this.state.toDoData.map(toDoDatum =>
            <TodoItem key={toDoDatum.id} details={{
                key: toDoDatum.id,
                text: toDoDatum.text,
                completed: toDoDatum.completed,
                onChange: this.handleOnChange
            }} />);
        return (
            <div>
                {toDoComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

TodoItem.js

```
import React from "react";

class TodoItem extends React.Component {

    properties = this.props.details;

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.properties.completed}
                    onChange={() => this.properties.onChange(this.properties.key)}
                />
                <span>{this.properties.text}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to assign your `details` prop to `properties` in your class? If you do that `properties` does not reflect the prop changes and your child component can't see the updates. Just use the props as it is:

```
render() {
  const { details } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={details.completed}
        onChange={() => details.onChange(details.key)}
      />
      <span>{details.text}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Also, since you don't use any state or lifecycle method in `TodoItem` component, it can be a functional component as well.

```
const TodoItem = ({ details }) => (
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={details.completed}
      onChange={() => details.onChange(details.key)}
    />
    <span>{details.text}</span>
  </div>
);
```

One more thing, why don't you pass the todo itself to `TodoItem` directly?

```
<TodoItem
  key={toDoDatum.id}
  todo={toDoDatum}
  onChange={this.handleOnChange}
/>
```

and

```
const TodoItem = ({ todo, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={todo.completed}
      onChange={() => onChange(todo.id)}
    />
    <span>{todo.text}</span>
  </div>
);
```

Isn't this more readable?

**Update after comment**

```js
const toDoData = [
  { id: 1, text: "foo", completed: false },
  { id: 2, text: "bar", completed: false },
  { id: 3, text: "baz", completed: false }
];

const TodoItem = ({ todo, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={todo.completed}
      onChange={() => onChange(todo.id)}
    />
    <span>{todo.text}</span>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      toDoData: toDoData
    };
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleOnChange(key) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let newState = prevState.toDoData.map(currentData => {
        if (currentData.id === key)
          currentData.completed = !currentData.completed;
        return currentData;
      });
      return { toDoData: newState };
    });
  }

  render() {
    let toDoComponents = this.state.toDoData.map(toDoDatum => (
      <TodoItem
        key={toDoDatum.id}
        todo={toDoDatum}
        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      />
    ));
    return <div>{toDoComponents}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I actually made the changes you suggested earlier about using the props as it is. It still doesn't update when I click on the checkbox....Oh and thanks for the suggestion, it actually is more readable

Comment: We can't say anything unless we see a working example. But, I've edited my answer and added a working code with my suggestions. It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks I copy-pasted your code and it worked, but I still can't figure out what I did wrong here cause it looks like the same code to me. Thanks a lot. You have no idea how long I've been on this.

Comment: You are welcome. As I said in my answer if you set your prop to a class instance like that it does not reflect the changes. This is why we have state and props in React. Do not mess with props like that :) Use them as they are. By the way, you don't need to use my exact code. It will work with `details` if you like it more. But, I think you are struggling too much there :)

Comment: The key take away here is that you should just use props! In you main section of code `this.props.onChange()` would have been the ideal scenario. Also `key` won’t ever be available within the component. Hence why you had to supply id. This was a good write up and example. Follow the follow of data 